# Add textEdit as child to row

Tags: qt, qt4

I want to add TextEdit as a child to QTreeWidget when chciking each row of treewidget.
Can someone help by giving clue.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have a TextEdit field as a row of a QTreeWidget as opposed to a plain text label/string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [setItemWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget)() function to set any widget you like to be at a given position in a treeview. An example might look like :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTreeWidget>
#include <QLineEdit>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{       
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QTreeWidget *tw = new QTreeWidget;

    // Add some sample items to the QTreeWidget
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        QStringList strings;
        strings << QString("Item %1").arg(i+1);
        QTreeWidgetItem *parent = new QTreeWidgetItem(strings);
        tw->addTopLevelItem(parent);


        // Add the child TreeWidgetItem one step down in the tree
        QTreeWidgetItem *child = new QTreeWidgetItem;
        parent->addChild(child);

        // Set the widget for the child item to be a QLineEdit for column zero.
        tw->setItemWidget(child, 0, new QLineEdit(tw));
    }

    tw->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This looks like this :

[image: Screenshot of TreeWidget]